# System.String[] Error while exporting csv for Azure Policy Assignment

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I wrote the below powershell script to get all Azure policy assignment within an azure subscription but when I try to export the result using `Export-CSV`, I get a `System.String[]` error for the NotScope row.

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object  ResourceGroupName 
ForEach-Object { (Get-AzPolicyAssignment).Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $mgId += [PSCustomObject]@{
      SubscriptionId    = $SubscriptionId
      SubscriptionName  = $subscriptionName
      ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName
      PolicyName        = $_.Name
      DisplayName       = $_.DisplayName
      Scope             = $_.Scope
      NotScope          = $_.NotScopes
    }
  }
}
$mgId | Export-CSV
```

Anyone know what I'm missing/

Comment: `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Csv` do not meaningfully support objects with properties that contain _collections_, such as arrays. If you want to
represent all collection elements in a CSV column value, you'll have to create a string representation of the collection yourself.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: As an aside: `System.String[]` isn't an _error_, it is how the _array_ contained in `$_.NotScopes` gets (meaninglessly) stringified by `Export-Csv`. That is, `.ToString()` is simply called; verify with `([string[]] 'foo').ToString()`. Also, your `ForEach-Object` call is receiving no input.

Comment: @mklement0 From reading your response here and in the linked duplicate, you suggested the script using this format PS> [pscustomobject] @{ col1 = 1; col2 = 2, 3 } | 
      Select-Object col1, @{ n='col2'; e={ $_.col2 -join ' ' } } |
        ConvertTo-Csv
"col1","col2"
"1","2 3" But when I do using Select-Object SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName, ResourceGroupName, PolicyName, DisplayName, Scope, @{ n='NotScope'; e={$_.NotScopes -join''}} |
                Export-CSV with the Export-CSV cmdlet rather than the ConvertTo-CSV, I get no information in the created CSV file,

Comment: To add, all of the variables created hold values, only the NotScope hold multiple values in some instances not all instance.

Comment: The `ConvertTo-Csv` command has pipeline input, which is necessary; your `Export-Csv` does not - perhaps you only omitted that for brevity (other than that, I see no issue). It's hard to troubleshoot in _comments_ and in any event this is a separate problem, so I encourage you to create a _new_ question post focused on the problem you now have, ideally in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: All I'm trying to do is to get Azure policy assignment for all the management group and output the Policy Name, Policy Display Name, Scope, NotScope to a csv file.

Comment: Understood. Now that  you're past the original problem, but are having trouble implementing the suggested solution, I again suggest creating a new question post, detailing the specific problem  you're _now_ having, including error messages, if any.